# Xcode 5 error Undefined Symbols for Architecture i386

Tags: xcode, class, architecture, undefined, symbols

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TraktAPIClient", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_kTraktAPIKey", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

This is the error I get when I try to compile my xcode program

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a library "TraktAPIClient" for i386. This library does not seems to contain any compiled code for this architecture. If you are building for iOS, you should target armv7 and armv7s.